# Android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class menu

Tags: xml, android-studio, inflate-exception

I have been following Udacity's "Developing Android Apps" course and I have stumbled upon a problem. In the tutorials, I am asked to create an XML file called `forecastfragment.xml`, which is below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

And I am told to inflate it into a fragment from a class called `ForecastFragment.java`, a process which happens on this line:

`View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.forecastfragment, container, false);`

My problem is that, when I try running the app, I get this error:

```
05-24 21:40:02.848 11882-11882/com.example.android.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.android.sunshine.app, PID: 11882
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.sunshine.app/com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class menu
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2431)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class menu
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                      at com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment.onCreateView(ForecastFragment.java:34)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:816)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                      at com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2431) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.menu" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sunshine.app-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.sunshine.app-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                      at com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment.onCreateView(ForecastFragment.java:34) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79) 
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:816) 
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                      at com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343) 
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2431) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

From the line:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.sunshine.app/com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class menu`

I am guessing that the problem is within the XML file, but I don't understand what could be wrong, as no errors are thrown. I'm thinking that, since I am new at this, it may be a simple error. Does anyone know why? Thank you so much in advance

Comment: I wish it was, but to my knowledge I'm not loading any images for a simple menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above mentioned xml file is a menu file. It is for adding menu items to you **action bar**.

So it cannot be inflated as your fragment layout file. First of all you need to create a layout file for your fragment.

Then you need to inflate **forecastfragment.xml** as menu for your **action bar**.

Follow below steps:

1.Create a normal layout xml file say **sample.xml** inside /res/layout/ and inflate it for your fragment by writing below line of code in **onCreateView**:

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, container, false);
```

2. Then override the function: **onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)** , inside that 
you will inflate your **forecastfragment.xml** like this:

```
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    return true;
```

Also add below line of code in your fragment's **onCreate** method:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

One more thing: Place your forecastfragment.xml inside /res/menu folder.

Comment: Now this is an answer. Thank you so much! I actually kept working on my question and had stumbled upon that same issue. It was as you said, I was using a menu as a layout (I actually had `forecastfragment.xml` under the layout folder!) and either way the Refresh menu item wouldn't appear because I was never letting the app know the fragment has options menu and I never did override the `onCreateOptionsMenu`. Thank you so much for your help!!